# orgmode: underscore automatically generates math-mode

Tags: org-mode, text-editing

When I type an underscore `_` in `org-mode`, it automatically generates math mode, i.e. `$_{}$` and it puts the cursor between the braces. Is there a way to disable this when in edit mode but not in math mode?

Comment: What does `C-h c _ RET` say? It should say `_ runs the command org-self-insert-command`. If you have any minor modes enabled, what are they? What do you mean by  `edit mode` and `math mode` in this context? What *IS* the context?

Comment: Since the underscore is the emphasis char for underlining I cannot imagine that what you describe is standard behavior. I guess you cannot reproduce the effect if you start emacs with `emacs -Q`. We cannot help you if you do not tell us what in your setup causes that behavior. On the other hand I assume that if you tell us the cause the solution will be quite simple.

Comment: @NickD @Tobias thank you, you are both right. I now understand that this was a feature of the `cdlatex` layer I am using. Therefore the question is kind of redundant. Do you think it is better to simply delete it?

Comment: Not necessarily: it might help somebody who does the same thing that you did. But that assumes that you can put a reasonably complete answer together (and yes, you can can answer your own question): without that, the question would be useless, but if you can explain what caused the problem and how to avoid it, that would be great - I, for one, would read it with interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end my question is not very smart. I am using `cdlatex` to type equations and math easily in `orgmode`. Then the answer is in the documentation under "PAIR INSERTION of (), [], {}, and $$":

> Also, the keys _ and ^ will insert "_{}" and "^{}", respectively, and, if necessary, also a pair of dollar signs to switch to math mode.

I didn't assume that this layer operates outside of equations, so I did not know this is the issue.

I am not sure if this is the desired behavior of `cdlatex` or not. Personally, I would prefer to be able to write underscores without the automatic addition of `_${}$`.

**UPDATE**

I got the behavior I wanted by setting up properly `smartparens` and by using `org-cdlatex-mode` (note that it is not `cdlatex-mode`). In this way the `cdlatex` behavior regarding underscores described above is only implemented inside equations (namely, inside `$ $`, `\( \)`, latex equations etc). When typing text, it does not generate any extra characters when typing `_`.

See the proper configuration in the answer of my other question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56094/21958).